# Imaginary $\delta$ in proof of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, continuity, epsilon-delta

> Define $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ as
>   $$f(x_1,x_2)=x_1+x_2$$
>   Prove that $f$ is continuous where the distance function on $\mathbb R^2$ is
>   $$d'(x,a)=\sqrt{(x_1-a_1)^2+(x_2-a_2)^2}$$

I went about proving this using the $\delta$ - $\epsilon$ definition of continuity. I chose $\delta=\sqrt{\epsilon-1}$. Then, given that
$$d'(x,a)\lt \delta$$
I need to derive
$$|f(x_1,x_2)-f(a_1,a_2)|\lt \epsilon$$
My derivation went like this:
$$d'(x,a)\lt \delta$$
$$\sqrt{(x_1-a_1)^2+(x_2-a_2)^2}\lt \sqrt{\epsilon-1}$$
$$(x_1-a_1)^2+(x_2-a_2)^2\lt \epsilon-1$$
Then, by a variation of the triangle inequality,
$$(x_1-a_1+x_2-a_2)^2\lt \epsilon-1$$
$$(x_1-a_1+x_2-a_2)^2+1\lt \epsilon$$
Then, using the fact that $n^2+1 \gt |x|$, 
$$|x_1+x_2-a_1-a_2|\lt \epsilon$$
$$|f(x_1,x_2)-f(a_1,a_2)|\lt \epsilon$$
And so the continuity of the function is proven.

My question is this: since I let
$$\delta=\sqrt{\epsilon-1}$$
it must be that when $\epsilon \lt 1$, $\delta$ is imaginary. Is this a problem, or is the proof still valid?

Do you see any other flaws in it?

Thanks!

Comment: It is a problem.  What does $d'(x,a)\lt \delta$ mean when  $\delta$ is not real?

Comment: @Henry ...I'm not sure. That's the problem. Can you suggest a better assignment of $\delta$?

Comment: I don't think $(x_1-a_1)^2+(x_2-a_2)^2\ge (x_1-a_1+x_2-a_2)^2$ as you use.

Comment: @WillFisher Ahh, good idea. Thank you!

Comment: @Nilknarf except looking back I don't think that inequality is true. It isn't if $(x_1-a_1)(x_2-a_2)>0$.

Comment: @WillFisher Hmm, maybe not... perhaps only if the individual numbers being squared each exceed or equal one.

Comment: `the distance function on R^2 is d′(x,a)` By definition, a metric (or "*distance*") is a function that takes non-negative *real* values. `d′(x,a) < δ` This makes no sense unless $\delta$ is a real number, since there is no inequality defined between complex numbers.

Comment: it seems that your function is Lipschitz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is mentioned in the comments $\delta$ might not be real.

If you want, you can do this:

Let $ \epsilon>0$

We have that $$|f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)|=|(x-x_0)+(y-y_0)| \leqslant$$ $$|x-x_0|+|y-y_0|= \sqrt{|x-x_0|^2}+ \sqrt{|y-y_0|^2} \leqslant$$ $$\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}+ \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}<2 \delta$$

Take $\delta= \epsilon /2 $ and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Set $\delta:=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, which is always positive if $\epsilon$ is. Then we calculate $$|x_1+x_2-a_1-a_2|\leq|x_1-a_1|+|x_2-a_2|=\sqrt{(x_1-a_1)^2}+\sqrt{(x_2-a_2)^2},$$ which we can estimate by $$\sqrt{(x_1-a_1)^2+(x_2-a_2)^2}+\sqrt{(x_2-a_2)^2+(x_1-a_1)^2}=2d'(x,a)<2\delta=\epsilon.$$

This proves the continuity of $f$.

EDIT: Whoops, Ramiz Karaeski has submitted essentially the same answer while I was typing.